# Looping of bash script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, ffmpeg

Once I start this `convertscript.sh` I want it to constantly check the files in the directory, if theres an `.mkv` it will convert it which it does fine at the moment, but when there are no `mkv` files left it seems to exit out the script, but I want it to loop and keep trying the script constantly.

Basically if a new file gets added say during the night because the script is looping constantly it picks it up, I don't want to run the `convertscript.sh` again.  I want to run `convertscript.sh` once initially and then not touch it.

The script I've got so far is below:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.mkv
do 
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -minrate 4.5M -maxrate 4.5M -bufsize 9M -c:a ac3 "${f%mkv}mp4";
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && rm "$f";
done
```

Comment: Consider using `cron` for that.

Comment: Investigate `inotifywatch`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop forever, you have to say so.

```sh
shopt -s globstar
while true; do
    for f in **/*.mkv; do 
        ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
            -minrate 4.5M -maxrate 4.5M -bufsize 9M \
            -c:a ac3 "${f%mkv}mp4" &&
        rm "$f"
    done
    # Don't consume CPU by looking for new files immediately
    sleep 1
done
```

Notice also how we avoid [the `$?` antipattern.](/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)  Maybe increase the `sleep` to five minutes or so once you are confident that this is working as planned.